# d3js multiple targets to a single node

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, d3.js

I'm using d3js to create a visual that is supposed to help me show dependencies of certain javascript files.

The current format that shows the relationship between the source and the target in d3 is:

```
var links = [
  { source: "A", target: "X"},
  { source: "Z", target: "Y"},
  { source: "A", target: "Z"},
  { source: "A", target: "W"},
];
```

Could anyone that is experienced with d3 and/or Javascript tell me how I can change the code so I can add multiple targets to look like:

```
var links = [
  { source: "A", target: "X", "Y", "Z"},
  { source: "Z", target: "Y"},
  { source: "A", target: "Z"},
  { source: "A", target: "W"},
];
```

Comment: Why do you now have 2 links from `A => Z`. First you don't have valid JS. Second it is a simple "flatten" operation. Test the type of the `target` field in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list several values in the `target` attributes, you can use a [Javascript array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

like so :

```
var links = [
  { source: "A", target: ["X", "Y", "Z"]},
  { source: "Z", target: "Y"},
  { source: "A", target: "Z"},
  { source: "A", target: "W"},
];
```

The array is created directly using the `[]` constructor. Actually `links` is also an array